# Declaring a Record with a Sharepoint Designer 2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, records-management, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I'm trying to use the SharePoint Records Management tools to handle archiving of records. I'm on SharePoint Online on a site that was migrated from 2010. I have a 2010 workflow that when a column in the item is set to "Complete", declares the item as a record. When I open the item, I can see that it says on the item "Declared Record 11/14/2019 2:23 PM". However, I can still edit the item, and when I look at the item in a view, the "Item is a Record" column says "No". When I try to log the value of "Item is a Record" in my workflow history, the log returns a blank - not Yes, not No, not any date/time/text value. Is there something else I need to be doing/looking into, or is this a problem with the site collection configuration? At the moment the workflow is running with my credentials, which are Site Collection Admin (Full control).

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate the feature "In-place Record Management" under Site Features and test it again :

Reference URL :
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4c6712e2-89ad-43bc-9913-fb053a664cf3/declare-record-not-working-on-item-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Looks like In-Place Record Management is not an available feature on our site. Is this dead in the water?

Comment: Please check this link :https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configuring-in-place-records-management-7707a878-780c-4be6-9cb0-9718ecde050a